# manipulate html content from ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
       $('p.example').text('change something');
   } 
}
```

How can I change the result of my callback? the result (in html format) appeared within the `id='content'` block, then I tried `$('p.example').text('change something');` it does nothing. I guess I have to manipulate it before I do the innerHTML?

Comment: Please provide a complete example HTML, JavaScript, etc...

Comment: Maybe you don't have a `p.example` element?

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery included....? And that you have a `paragraph` with the class of `example`?

Comment: @FelixKling I have..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I put this even within the document.ready scope.. and my selector is correct.

Comment: try this `alert($('p.example').length)` rigth before trying to change the text( or right after) in same `if` block. Nothing wrong with code shown if that selector exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parseHTML()` to convert it to an html object, then do your manipulation as you normally would on any other html element.

```
$.ajax(url,function(data){
  var $html = $.parseHTML(data);
  $("body",$html).append("Adding this text to my html result.");
  ....
});
```